# PostGIS help writing a ST_MakeSimple method for self intersecting lines?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, line, self-intersection

I have imported Open Street Map lines into PostGIS 2.1 and I need to clean up the self intersecting ways. I have done some manual edits in the past but there are many more `ST_IsSimple(way) = false` than I have time to do by hand. Is there a quick way to find rings and split off their dangles? I would like to write a `ST_MakeSimple(the_geom)` function for handling these in the future, it would be equivalent to `ST_MakeValid(the_geom)` that makes polygons valid.

An example is shown selected in green in the image. What will make it simple is to cut the tail off of the ring.

[image: Looped linestring with a tail]

For the linestring pictured above `ST_IsSimple(ST_Node(way))` is false. Adding nodes is not able to self intersection. However the linestring below is fixed, it just doubles back on itself, so it can be made simple.
[image: A linestring that doubles back on itself]

Comment: Might [ST_Node](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Node.html) be what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the idea it works for about 10% of the non-simple lines, the number went from 78 to 72 after ST_Node.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: I posted some images, one where ST_Node does not work, and one where it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query converts 85% of of the linestrings in my sample of not simple linestrings to being `ST_IsSimple` equal to true. I realized after I posted my question that my situation is similar to this [previously answered post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13544/split-edges-at-intersections-in-postgis?rq=1). In my case the majority of the lines are made simple by splitting the tails off of rings by using the end point of the ring: `ST_Split(way, ST_EndPoint(way))`. Interestingly, in my sample the rings never begin at the start point of the line so splitting using the start point did not have any effect. At the end I union in the linestrings that are made simple using `ST_Node` per [Michal Zimmermann](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/8246/michal-zimmermann)'s suggestion in the comments to my original question. 
NOTE that calling ST_Split on linestrings that have already been ST_Node'd will create non-simple features, so they need to be excluded and unioned back on at the end. 
Also NOTE that I have added a unique id 'gid' to planet_osm_line to account for the non-unique nature of osm_id after osm2pgsql import.
Also NOTE that it would probably be good to create new gid's for the split features.

```
WITH A AS
( SELECT gid, ST_IsSimple(way) AS simple, 
    ST_IsSimple(ST_Node(way)) AS simple_afternode, 
    way AS geom--ST_IsSimple() AS simple--, ST_IsSimple(St_Node(way)) AS noded
  FROM planet_osm_line
  WHERE ST_IsSimple(way) = false)

( SELECT S.gid, S.simple, S.simple_afternode, 
    ST_IsSimple(S.geom) AS simple_aftersplitend, S.geom
  FROM 
  ( SELECT A.gid, simple, simple_afternode, 
     (ST_Dump(ST_Split(A.geom,ST_EndPoint(A.geom)))).geom AS geom
    FROM A
    WHERE simple_afternode <> true
  ) AS S
  ORDER BY simple, simple_afternode, simple_aftersplitend, gid
)

UNION ALL

( SELECT N.gid, N.simple, N.simple_afternode, false AS simple_aftersplitend, N.geom
  FROM 
  ( SELECT A.gid, simple, simple_afternode, geom
    FROM A
    WHERE simple_afternode = true
  ) AS N
  ORDER BY simple, simple_afternode, simple_aftersplitend, gid
)
```