# ST_Contains when linestring crossing itself

Tags: postgis, crossing

I have a linestring which crosses itself, like in the picture below. There isn't any vertice at the crossing.

[image]

It is a MultiLinestring, so when I want to get the startpoint, the endpoint, or the azimuth (for instance), I get an empty result. I tried to use ST_Linemerge, but for the same result. I think the problem come from the fact that this linestring is crossing itself since I don't have that problem with the linestrings (in the same table) which don't cross themselves.

I am trying to get xmin, xmax, azimuth... in order to establish a process for an atlas in QGIS. I would prefer to manage that in PostGIS, do you have any idea on the way to go?

In my experience these self-crossing linestrings are a big source of problems (with ST_Dump for example), problems that nor me nor my colleagues ever managed to solve, so any insight would be very welcome.

Comment: You tried to use the function ST_MakeValid? Until you provide an example of code and geodata, it’s hard to help ...

Comment: Specify, the azimuth is determined from one point to another, https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Azimuth.html,  how is this process connected with the intersection, which as you say you don’t have?

Comment: I am not sure to understand you second comment. I am using the azimuth to calculate a rotated bounding box. And to use it I need the startpoint and endpoint of a line, which in the case of a multilinestring doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe I didn’t understand something, but you have a function ST_DumpPoints...

Answer (score 2):

Self-intersecting linestring is valid but it is not simple as you can test in PostGIS with

```
select st_isvalid(
ST_geomfromtext(
'LINESTRING (440 380, 560 460, 620 380, 540 320, 480 480)'));

->true
```

and

```
select st_issimple(
ST_geomfromtext(
'LINESTRING (440 380, 560 460, 620 380, 540 320, 480 480)'));

->false
```

ST_MakeValid does not do anything for self-intersecting linestrings because they are already valid and there is no ST_MakeSimple even it has been under discussion several years ago https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/399.

Best advice for making linestrings simple is perhaps in gis.stackexchange [PostGIS help writing a ST_MakeSimple method for self intersecting lines?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186340/postgis-help-writing-a-st-makesimple-method-for-self-intersecting-lines).

Answer (score 1):

For making a self-intersecting linestring simple you must split the line at the intersection points. It may be necessary to create a new node at the intersection point first. OpenJUMP has a special utility "Noder" for that purpose.

Self-intersecting linestring to start with.

[image]

Dialog box of the Noder tool that is available in OpenJUMP Plus through menu Tools - Edit Geometry - Noder.

[image]

The result is three simple linestrings. New node added by OpenJUMP emphasized.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However it doesn't give me the expected result since I would get 3 linestrings instead of a single one. Well I guess I could then imagine a process to get the values I want through those 3 linestrings, but it would be a quite heavy process for a relatively marginal situation.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is a `MultiLineString` with only one component, you can use [ST_GeometryN](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.5/ST_GeometryN.html) to get the component `LineString`, and then run the functions needed on that.